# calling begin() or end() on a templated data structure

Tags: c++, templates

I am trying to use the `remove_if` STL function, and am passing in either a map, unordered_map, or vector. All of which carry the functions `.begin()` and `.end()` which return iterators. The compiler is not allowing me to call the functions on the templated variable

I have tried using both the `.begin()` and `.end()` as well as `begin()` and `end()`

```
template<typename FUNCTOR, typename datastructure>
void deleteFromHelper(FUNCTOR func, datastructure table)
{
    std::remove_if(table.begin(), table.end(), func);
}
```

where table is either an unorded_map, map, or vector. and func is a custom functor

The Compiler says: 
`Error  C2228    left of '.begin' must have class/struct/union`

Comment: Present your [mcve].

Comment: And state your exact toolchain and OS

Comment: How are you calling this function, ie. what types for `datastructure` are you using? Are you sure you're passing in a type which has a `begin()` and `end()` member? If you remove the calling code then perhaps the error goes away.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like an MSVC bug, gcc is perfectly happy with it, see:

https://wandbox.org/permlink/KuzZrEriPQerBoou

But, if using template deduction as my example does, did you specify /std:c++17? (And I think this might still be incomplete in MSVC).

Comment: g++ says: `error: ‘remove_if’ is not a member of ‘std’
  std::remove_if(table.begin(), table.end(), func);` I did not specify c++17

Comment: Don't forget `#include <algorithm>`

Comment: algorithm is included

Comment: And `-std=c++17`

Comment: where can i add this? - visual studio 19

Comment: VC++ is happy too https://rextester.com/live/DPMIQ82859 including with /std:c++14

Comment: Would be a pretty strange bug. Calling a function on an argument of template-parameter type? Totally normal thing to do.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I went by what the OP told me.  Guess I should have checked...

Comment: _where can i add this?_ Please edit it into the original question, along with the code invoking the template.